# Object not visible in render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I've spent hours searching the internet trying to solve this problem.

I have a green ball in my scene which is emitting particles. Ball is visible everywhere but the render, I have render icon in outliner turned on, duplication in object settings set to *None*, I've tried changing materials and moving it between layers but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Answer (score 1):

Try going in the Properties Tab>Particle system>Render and make sure the "Show emitter is turned on"

Comment: Thank you for reply, but emitter is already turned on and works just fine, ball stil ivisible in render though.